# Vertically align an image in a div using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying vertical align an image in a `div`. I have a `div` which displays a coloured background and I need to place other objects inside that `div`, but centred vertically.

[image: Trying to align the arrow with the word Ground]

I have craeted a sjfiddle to try and explain.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Blackbox/2k5zhbLd/11/)

Comment: Why are you setting gray background? Maybe you need gradient?

Comment: Why do you use so many wrapper blocks in your markup?

Comment: Try giving an example of the result you would want. The HTML and CSS provided is pretty convoluted.

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov  thanks for looking and the edit. There are a number of elements that I have not included which is why there are so many blocks. I did not want to clutter the code with the other stuff.

Comment: can you show your output image that you want to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should get rid of the `margin-top: -60px` in `.room-name` . Then there are two texts, not just one. Take a look at the settings below, I think that might be what you want (?) The essential part for the centering is the relative position, to: 50% and transform: translatey(-50%), but also the background position for the background image.

```css
#wrapper-new {
  width: 100%;
}

#record-section {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #333;
  height: 80px;
}

#room-section {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #E9E9E9;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
}

.direction-image {
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://s2.postimg.org/te7o9w9ix/orbitor_small_17.png);
  background-position: 0 center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.room-name {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #006;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.floor-name {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper-new">
  <div id="record-section">
    <div id="room-section">
      <div class="direction-image">
        <div class="room-name">Box
          <div class="floor-name">Ground</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To vertically center children you just need to add `display: flex` and `align-items: center` for element immediate parent and all its children will be centered vertically.

Using your markup it will be something like (also removed negative `top-margin` from your styles):

```css
#wrapper-new {
  width: 100%;
}

#record-section {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #333;
  height: 80px;
}

#room-section {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #E9E9E9;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
}

.direction-image {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://s2.postimg.org/te7o9w9ix/orbitor_small_17.png);
}

.room-name {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #006;
  /* remove display: inline-block; */
  display: flex; /* new */
  align-items: center; /* new */
  /* remove margin-top: -60px; */
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.floor-name {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper-new">
  <div id="record-section">
    <div id="room-section">
      <div class="direction-image">
        <div class="room-name">Box
          <div class="floor-name">Ground</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worth noting that it is only supported by new browser versions.

Comment: @VladoPandžić Accoding to [can-i-use](https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) flexbox has 97.5% device support now so I'm not sure that this feature is so "new" to care about this. After 1-2 years this note will be useless at all.

Comment: Yes, I saw that but because it is property that affects whole layout and in some countries IE explorer has 10-20% marker share, and because in some companies you can not just remove IE<11 support (like in company I work for)

Comment: @VladoPandžić Flexbox works for IE10+. It's not often you need to support earlier version. Somebody who needs to support them should ask for this in question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use flexbox (which is not supported by older browsers) you can add *line-height: 100px* (or some other number) (if parent has height `100px`)

```css
.box{
height:100px;
width:100px;
color:white;
background-color:red;
line-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Text inside box
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try flexbox: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Larpee/6L2s3cLg/).

```
  <div id="wrapper-new">
  <div id="record-section">
    <div id="room-section">
         <div class="direction-image"> 
            <div class="room-name">Box
              <div class="floor-name">Ground</div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

You can change how you vertically align inner items by changing the wrapper's align-items property to center.